# Selenium Webdriver SSL Certificate Hostname Mismatch Problem

Tags: ssl, selenium, webdriver, hostname, mismatch

I have recently run into problems using the .NET version of Selenium Webdriver to run tests against a website running in a test environment where the SSL certificate does not match the hostname it’s served from.

To make Firefox accept the SSL certificate while it is controlled by Selenium, I have tried using firefoxProfile.SetPreference("browser.ssl_override_behavior", 1) and firefoxProfile.AcceptUntrustedCertificates but have not been successful.

Is there any other way I can resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help,

Brett

Comment: Did you try to set AcceptUntrustedCertificates to false? That's usually the solution if the certificate is valid (trusted issuer) but doesn't match the host name.

Answer (score 2):

the way we got around this was hacking local hosts file...